# Как закрывать или скрывать BottomSheetBehavior по кнопке?

Tags: android, android-bottomsheetbehavior

Нужно BottomSheet показывать по кнопке и скрывать по кнопке, но со скрытием есть проблемы.

```
private void closeBottomSheet() {
    bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вообщем, решил проблему

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(layout_bottom);
}


private void closeBottomSheet() {
    bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
}
```